# Ruby load module in test

Tags: ruby, sinatra, minitest, padrino, rack-test

I am running a padrino application and have started with the included mailers. I want to test that a mail is sent and had previously had no trouble accessing the Mail::TestMailer object to look at the mails delivered during the test.

That is the background about what I am doing but not precisely the question. I want to know how can a module become available to the runtime environment.
I have this test in two versions

first

```
def test_mailer
  Mail::TestMailer.deliveries.clear
  get '/owners/test'
  e =  Mail::TestMailer.deliveries.pop
  puts e.to.to_s
end
```

second

```
def test_mailer
  get '/owners/test'
  Mail::TestMailer.deliveries.clear
  e =  Mail::TestMailer.deliveries.pop
  puts e.to.to_s
end
```

In the second version this test fails with the error message `NoMethodError: undefined method to' for nil:NilClass` This makes sense to me. I clear the messages then ask for the last one which should be nil. However when I run the test on the first version the error is `NameError: uninitialized constant OwnersControllerTest::Mail`

So somehow the get method is causing the `Mail` object/module to be made available. I don't understand how it can do this. I don't know if this is a rack-test or padrino thing so am unsure what extra information to copy in here.

Comment: `OwnersControllerTest` (and therefore `OwnersControllerTest::Mail`) isn't defined in Padrino's codebase, is it from yours? If so, it looks like a file you need isn't being `require`d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `require 'mail'` to your test helper.

The issue is explained here: https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/issues/1797